# How to use google material design icons for HTML image control instead of image url?

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, image, google-material-icons

Sample HTML code

```
<img  id="PartId" title="Test Part" class="visible-lg visible-md visible-sm" onclick="func1();" src="../theme1/buttons/add.png">

<i class="material-icons">add_circle</i>
```

I don't want to display the image from the path, but to display material icon instead in the image control

Please help!

Comment: Please clarify what you mean when you "don't want to display the image from the path, but to display material icon instead in the image control"? Are you trying to place the Add icon inside the image container?

Comment: Yes, I want to display icon in the container and not the image from the url

Comment: Don't use the "image control". Just use the `<i class="material-icons">add_circle</i>` HTML.

Comment: Use a `<div></div>` for your container or something similar and then just place the `<i class="material-icons">add_circle</i>` in there. Don't use the <img/> component

Comment: It is HTML image control only

Comment: Its difficult to remove the img control as there are some dependencies and its been used many places in the code base

Comment: Assuming that you never searching it by img but from id, you can change <img> tag with a simple <div> and remove src property and put the icon inside it.

Comment: Thank you all who reviewed and tried to help with this question. Replacing the tag to div on run time would run into more issues later, one solution would be to use a different control which supports material design icon tag so that it can be used as it is.. but it may need more testing.